# Apply same extension for multiple enums in dart

Tags: dart, enums

Is there a possibility to apply the same dart extension to multiple enums? Here is my enum and extension.

```
enum Currency {
  EUR, INR, USD, CNY, JPY, GBP
}

extension ParseToString on Currency {
  String toShortString() {
    return this.toString().split('.').last;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to make it like

```
enum InvoiceStatus {
  DRAFT, SENT, PAID, PARTIALLY_PAID
}

extension ParseToString on Currency, InvoiceStatus {
  String toShortString() {
    return this.toString().split('.').last;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there isn't a way to add an extension to multiple enums, since dart `2.14` all enums extends a common interface: [Enum](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.14.0-388.0.dev/dart-core/Enum-class.html). That allows you to add an extensions to all enums:

```dart
extension on Enum {
  String toShortString() {
    return this.toString().split('.').last;
  }
}
```

after so you can use `.toShortString()` to any enum object.

Comment: Is there a way to access the `ThisEnum.values`?